In maven dependency folder, dependencies are not loading showing [without test code]
I am working on Spring application, upgrading from java 8 (spring boot version 2.6.7) to java 17(spring boot 3.2.6) ,
I have two projects , project A dependent on project B ,As jars of project B should be loaded into maven dependency path of project A , but it is not getting loaded it is showing project B[without test code] in dependency of project A.
Checked for version mismatch also it is correctly mapped.
Previously in java 8 it was working fine , jars were getting loaded.
IDE used : STS
Thanks in advance.

(1) Terminal, Command: mvn clean install (2) In File browser , delete .settings,.classpath,.project (3) STS , File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects

There are different ways how a (Maven) project can depend on another project. One way is that the project depends on the JAR of the other project that needs to be built each time when it is updated. Another way is that a project directly depends on the other project so changes will be seen immediately when a change is made in the other project. It is unclear what you exactly did and what you exactly want. Please provide a minimal reproducible example including the pom.xml file(s).

@life888888 The question is about Eclipse, so a terminal is not required at all. It seems you use deleting .settings, .classpath and .project, followed by re-importing instead of just right-clicking the project and choosing Configure > Convert to Maven project. Note that most of the settings stored in the .settings folder have nothing to do with Maven and deleting them will cause the settings that have been explicitly made as project specific to be lost.

A good test of whether eclipse got confused is to create a fresh workspace and clone your sources from git again.
In my experience this fixes most of these things (except if you have happened to check in eclipse files not intended to be checked in - this is why you are suggested in a comment to delete these by hand)

To be clear, the files .classpath and .project and the .settings folder are intended to be shared. Don't gitignore them. Those files are in the project folder and not handled as meta data in order to be shared. Not sharing these files is a common misconception. Please stop spreading this nonsense any further.

@howlger my personal opinion is that for maximum maintainability Maven projects should be IDE-agnostic to avoid subtle vendor lock in, and allowing everybody to choose the best tool for the job at hand.  The world is more than Eclipse.  Everybody gets the same to start with.  Site wide IDE-configuration should be centrally configured, not in the code repositories.  Please don’t encourage bad habits that will not scale to large professional teams.

No, this does not lead to a vendor lock-in. These files are intended to be shared independent of which IDE or IDEs you use. Sharing these files makes it easy to onboard people to projects: simply clone the project and you are ready to run or to debug the application without any additional steps that would otherwise be necessary. It is the easiest way to share settings that would otherwise need to be documented and applied manually (which often does not happen in reality). What you say is unprofessional and doesn't scale. It is not the IDE that is confused. An IDE is just a deterministic tool.

@howlger Anything that hides functionality in IDE-specific configuration files may possibly lead to different behaviour with other IDE's.   Especially with Maven which contains all the information needed on its own to reproduce the original build.  In my opinion there should not be ANY  IDE-specific files in a Maven source tree - any additionally needed configuration should happen elsewhere.   Please do not advocate bad habits as truths.

No, that is not what these files are for and how they work. All IDEs have independently implemented what you call bad habits. So go and implement your own IDE without these bad habits. Or use Maven, which can be used also as an IDE, as you say. And by the way, I don't care that my latest answer gets voted down every time I prove you wrong.

I don't think I said Maven can be used as an IDE.  And I have not said that IDE's should not have the files they need ot function, you just shouldn't check those into git that the Maven support in the IDE's recreate when importing.   Perhaps it is clearer now?
